# What is the general understanding of "graduation"?

Tags: word-meaning

[Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/graduation) defines the word "graduation" as below.

> Graduation is the successful completion of a course of study at a
> university, college, or school, for which you receive a degree or
> diploma.

If someone has finished his/her "certificate program" at school, do you still say "He/She is graduated from (school name)?

Comment: In British usage, _graduation_ normally refers to the completion of a first degree at university. I suspect US usage differs.

Comment: How about "high school graduate"? Don't you use the words in UK?

Comment: We don't have 'high school graduates' in the UK. Pupils leave _secondary school_ with, or without, qualifications gained in examinations sat at ages 16 and 18. The UK education system is different from that of the US.